# Facing difficulty in mapping an XML from flat file format using Altova MapForce

Tags: xml, xsd, altova, map-force

I have managed to map each line by splitting them horizontally. 
The problem comes when `(Q1, Q2)` and (Q3, Q4) are not coming together under their respective enclosing tags. Also, we need to take care of a group of lines repeating. Like in the example below I have first two lines repeated again.

Q12222222222
Q21111111111
Q13333333333
Q24444444444
Q35555555555
Q46666666666

**Target XSD** file given below:

```
<xs:schema>
    <xs:element name="Statement">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="StatementDetails" type="StatementDetailsT" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                <xs:element name="FinalStatement" type="FinalStatementT" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:complexType name="StatementDetailsT">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Q1" type="Q1_T" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="Q2" type="Q2_T" maxOccurs="1"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="FinalStatementT">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Q3" type="Q3_T" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="Q4" type="Q4_T" maxOccurs="1"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="Q1_T">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element type="st:string2" name="cIdentifier" fixed="Q1" />
            <xs:element type="st:string10" name="sNumber" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="Q2_T">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element type="st:string2" name="cIdentifier" fixed="Q2" />
            <xs:element type="st:string11" name="antiDumpingDuty" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="Q3_T">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element type="st:string2" name="cIdentifier" fixed="Q3" />
            <xs:element type="st:string10" name="sNumber" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="Q4_T">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element type="st:string2" name="cIdentifier" fixed="Q4" />
            <xs:element type="st:string11" name="antiDumpingDuty" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

**Expected XML** should look like given below:

```
    <Statement>
        <StatementDetails>
            <Q1>
                <cIdentifier>Q1</cIdentifier>
                <sNumber>2222222222</sNumber>
            </Q1>
            <Q2>
                <cIdentifier>Q2</cIdentifier>
                <antiDumpingDuty>1111111111</antiDumpingDuty>
            </Q2>
        </StatementDetails>
        <StatementDetails>
            <Q1>
                <cIdentifier>Q1</cIdentifier>
                <sNumber>3333333333</sNumber>
            </Q1>
            <Q2>
                <cIdentifier>Q2</cIdentifier>
                <antiDumpingDuty>4444444444</antiDumpingDuty>
            </Q2>
        </StatementDetails>
        <FinalStatement>
            <Q3>
                <cIdentifier>Q3</cIdentifier>
                <sNumber>5555555555</sNumber>               
            </Q3>
            <Q4>
                <cIdentifier>Q4</cIdentifier>
                <antiDumpingDuty>6666666666</antiDumpingDuty>
            </Q4>
        </FinalStatement>
    </Statement>
```

I have applied split in following order:

1. Repeated Split with Mode:delimited(line starts with), 
   Reg-ex:Yes, pattern: `^Q[13]`
   This divides data into 3 segments of two rows each.
2. Switch contains regular expression : `^Q[12]`, `^Q[34]`.
3. Then each output of step-2 is applied with Repeated split horizontally, 
   this divides each segment into single lines.
   Which then applied with multiple split once depending upon column length.

Split and Mapping diagrams attached for reference.
[image: Split Diagram]
[image: Mapping Diagram]

**Actual XML** file produced by mapping is given below:

```
<Statement>
    <StatementDetails>
        <Q1>
            <cIdentifier>Q1</cIdentifier>
            <sNumber>2222222222</sNumber>
        </Q1>
    </StatementDetails>
    <StatementDetails>
        <Q2>
            <cIdentifier>Q2</cIdentifier>
            <antiDumpingDuty>1111111111</antiDumpingDuty>
        </Q2>
    </StatementDetails>
    <StatementDetails>
        <Q1>
            <cIdentifier>Q1</cIdentifier>
            <sNumber>3333333333</sNumber>
        </Q1>
    </StatementDetails>
    <StatementDetails>
        <Q2>
            <cIdentifier>Q2</cIdentifier>
            <antiDumpingDuty>4444444444</antiDumpingDuty>
        </Q2>
    </StatementDetails>
    <FinalStatement>
        <Q3>
            <cIdentifier>Q3</cIdentifier>
            <sNumber>5555555555</sNumber>
        </Q3>
    </FinalStatement>
    <FinalStatement>
        <Q4>
            <cIdentifier>Q4</cIdentifier>
            <antiDumpingDuty>6666666666</antiDumpingDuty>
        </Q4>
    </FinalStatement>
</Statement>
```

Please someone suggest what is going wrong in the structure or mapping? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

when you connect "RepeatedSplit - horizontal" to "StatementDetails", your mapping will create a "StatementDetails" tag each time the event "RepeatedSplit - horizontal" is found.

This could explain why Q1 and Q2 are not grouped.

I can suggest you to delete this connection, and instead to add a second connection starting from "ROW Q1" to "StatementDetails".

I guess it should create the "StatementDetails" tag only when "Q1" is found.

I am not able to test right now the solution that I am proposing.

Could test and let us know if it worked for you?